# iOS app transport security: Allow certain IP addresses in Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, security, react-native, plist

The security settings seem to be correct, but my React Native app for some reason doesn't connect to the server (neither when running on iOS device or simulator).

The server (ip address and port) is visible on the network, so the error is probably caused by the `NSAppTransportSecurity` inside `Info.plist`. Restarting it doesn't help.

A working solution is setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `true` to open the addresses. As far as I know, it exposes all IP addresses and therefore should be avoided.

`NSExceptionDomains` seem to only work with domain names and not IP addresses.

How to open the `10.10.0.16` and `localhost` IP addresses and block all others?

App Transport Security Settings:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>10.10.0.16</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Console log:

```
2016-07-26 17:14:26.803 RNProject[80649:678556] NSMainNibFile and UIMainStoryboardFile are both set. NSMainNibFile ignored.
2016-07-26 17:14:26:936 RNProject[80649:678556] styleString = styleFile
2016-07-26 17:14:27.005 RNProject[80649:678837] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
2016-07-26 17:14:27.021 RNProject[80649:678556]  INFO: Reveal Server started (Protocol Version 25).
2016-07-26 17:14:27.035 RNProject[80649:678556] Reachability: Reachable via WiFi
2016-07-26 17:14:27.035 RNProject[80649:678556] Reach = Reachability: Reachable via WiFi
2016-07-26 17:14:27.036 [fatal][tid:main] Could not connect to development server.

Ensure the following:
- Node server is running and available on the same network - run 'npm start' from react-native root
- Node server URL is correctly set in AppDelegate

URL: http://10.10.0.16:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
```

Comment: This just started happening to me this week.  It seems to be happening with iOS 10.2 and higher.  I will note, that the latest documentation, the word "Temporary" is no longer used in the key names. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33
However, correcting the key names did not fix the problem.  The app seems to be ignoring the domains list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly the only solution is to set `<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>` in the development version to load React Native libraries and switch it off in release.